# Link AdWords + Google Analytics + BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-ads-api

We have connected AdWords to our Google Analytics views and it works: AdWords campaigns are shown in Google Analytics. For deeper analysis we would like to analyze the data also in BigQuery.

We have setup the import from Google Analytics to BigQuery using a data view which is linked to AdWords. The import itself works, but if we search in BigQuery for TrafficCampaigns with TrafficMedium = cpc (AdWords-Campaigns), the campaigns are missing (null).

We are also importing all AdWords data directly to BigQuery, but we could not find how to relate this data to the Google Analytics data.

Does anybody know how this works? What do we have to do to link the AdWords campaigns with the Google Analytics data in BigQuery?

Thanks for your help!
Kind regards,
Al

[Screenshot of GA-Export in BQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvnzL.png)

Comment: It's important to give  more context in order to provide you help. Did you use the [BigQuery Export for Analytics guide](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437618?hl=en)? Are you seeing any [error message](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6377041?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089#) during the export? Also it will be helpful an screenshot of your exported tables

Comment: Dear Enrique, thank you for your comment. I think we have studied the relevant guidelines. The analytics to BigQuery-Export is running without any problems since more than two years; just the adwords campaigns are missing. For me it would actually helpful to know how it should work: If I link Adwords to Google Analytics should the adwords campaign be included in the GA BigQuery-Export? Or do we have to do this another way?

Comment: P.S. I have included a screenshot of the GA BigQuery table - at least the top as it is very long...